# GCP Managed VM Cloud Debugger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm having trouble getting the cloud debugger to catch on a snapshot and am not sure where to turn next.

I am running a Django App on a Managed VM (python-compat) runtime and using CloudSQL as a database.

I have connected the source repository seemingly OK, and my environment shows as an available app to debug in the console: https://console.cloud.google.com/debug

When I set a point on the code, it listens to take a snapshot, but it never captures anything.

I have the following in my wsgi file as docs suggest.

```
try:
  import googleclouddebugger
  googleclouddebugger.AttachDebugger()
except ImportError:
  pass
```

Is there anything obvious that might cause the debugger to not catch? I named my version "staging" so I'm sure there is only 1 and I'm looking at the correct deployed instance.  Debugging worked just fine before I switched to the "flexible" runtime from the standard app engine python runtime.

Comment: Sometimes this can happen if you don't have the right module selected in the UI.  It's especially common if you have multiple modules in one source code repository.

Comment: thanks @JustinBeckwith. I only have 1 module available, so I'm sure I have the right one. In the "Standard" AppEngine environment everything "just works", but I haven't been able to get the "Flexible" environment working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Alright - I think I have better answers now :)  Turns out there was a problem the python-compat runtime and the debugger - so we had to turn it off while we fixed the problem.  The underlying issue is fixed, but we haven't quite re-integrated enabling it by default:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-vm-runtime/pull/72/files

You should be able to add google-python-cloud-debugger to your requirements.txt and see things light up.  Apologies for the trouble!

Comment: Thanks @JustinBeckwith I appreciate your reply. I do have that in my requirements file and I still can't get anything to hit on the debugger with the python-compat runtime... standard runtime works beautifully

Comment: @Aaron I face the same issue with one of my projects. The python-compat runtime image does not to be related to the [open source one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-vm-runtime). I tried to find if the python-compat image comes with this fix but unfortunately I did not find any answer.